# Toggling the background image of div on click using Javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick, styles

Hi there I am trying to use Javascript to toggle the background image of a div when clicked

This is what I have done to try and achieve this:

My code is as follows

HTML:

```
<div id="AccordionContainer" class="AccordionContainer">
    <div onclick="runAccordion(1);">
        <div class="AccordionTitle" id="Accordion1Title" onselectstart="return false;" onclick="changeArrow(1);" >
            Instructions
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Accordion1Content" class="AccordionContent">  
        <p>Enter in your search parameters by clicking on the title of... </p>
    </div>

    <div onclick="runAccordion(2);">
        <div class="AccordionTitle" id="Accordion2Title" onselectstart="return false;" onclick="changeArrow(2);" >
            Colour
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Accordion2Content" class="AccordionContent">  
        [wpv-control field="cultivar-category" type="checkboxes" values="Dark Red" url_param="cultivar-category"]
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function changeArrow(index)
{
    var arrowID = "Accordian" + index + "Title";    
    document.getElementById(arrowID).style.background="url(./img/accordian-title-up.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent"; 
}
```

However nothing happens when I click on a div that contains onclick="runAccordion(index);"

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>`runAccordion` is maybe overriding or blocking `changeArrow`, depending on the structure of your HTML. Try combining them in the same onclick listener (`runAccordion(1);changeArrow(1);`) and see what happens there.</strike>

Also, if you've fixed this, check your image path.

EDIT

You have a typo:

`var arrowID = "Accordian" + index + "Title";`

should be:

`var arrowID = "Accordion" + index + "Title";`

Comment: Thanks for the response The image path works I just changed it for this example now in order not to reveal the url of the site I'm working on I think my problem lies here with –

    var arrowID = "Accordian" + index + "Title";

Because when I used 
   
    document.getElementById("Accordion2Title").style.background="url(./img/accordian-title-up.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent"; 

I did get a result

Comment: No problem, it was actually pretty easy to see in the dev console once I ran your code.

Comment: If I wanted to toggle the image eg: 1st click change to accordian-title-up.png and then upon click of the same div or any other div with changeArrow(index) change to accordian-title.png how would I go about it? Sorry I am very new to javascript.

Comment: If you're new to JS, then it might be a good idea to use jQuery, see [this](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) function for the accordion; and about the image changing you need to check what's the current image and change it to the other one. About posting such questions, it's always better to try it yourself so you can tell people about what problem you're having and not asking people to do your work.

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to select the answer if it helped you.